# Windows home server mount don't work properly

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab

I want to permanently mount my windows home server folders. My account work properly on every windows machine and this is the first time i want to mount it on linux.

For every shared folder i make a rule in fstab:

```
//192.168.1.3/Downloads /home/janco/mnt/downloads  cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
//192.168.1.3/Pictures /home/janco/mnt/afbeeldingen  cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
//192.168.1.3/Films /home/janco/mnt/films cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
//192.168.1.3/Music /home/janco/mnt/music cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
//192.168.1.3/Serie's /home/janco/mnt/series cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
//192.168.1.3/Videos /home/janco/mnt/videos cifs username=Janco,password=--- 0 0
```

The mount works, i can read my files. But when i try to create a direcotry or change a file, i get a permission error: acces denied.

I have change the permission of the " /mnt"  folder (with chmod) but this doesn't help. I can create a folder in the mnt folder, but not in a shared folder.

What could be the problem?

Some information about the server:
OS: Windows home server 2011
Static ip: 192.168.1.3
Server name: FILESERVER

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting the RW (read write) switch...  Like this for example:

```
//192.168.1.3/Videos /home/janco/mnt/videos cifs username=Janco,password=---,rw 0 0
```

I presumed that your "---" is where you put your password.

or this:

```
//192.168.1.3/Videos /home/janco/mnt/videos cifs  username=Janco,password=password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
```

or even this:

```
//192.168.1.3/Videos /home/janco/mnt/videos smbfs  username=guest,password=,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
```

Comment: Tried this but no result, stil no permissions. The weird thing is when i do 

mkdir /hoem/janco/mnt/videos/test

i have no permissions to create the directory. 

But when i do 
sudo mkdir /home/janco/mnt/videos/test

it works.

Comment: Can you connect manually using this command:  smbclient //server/share -U user%password

Comment: Yes i can connect manually. I can also connect through  files -> entire network -> connect to server. It workes fine but i want a permanently mount.

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional solution.  Try that one and see if it works.

Comment: Again not working :( I can still read my shared folders but i don't have any write permissions. I can only write if i'm super user (sudo).

Comment: Added yet another solution, this time using samba ;)  If this one doesn't work either, dump me some specifics of your server OS and network.

Comment: First i install samba with sudo apt-get install samba. Added the line to fstab, but while mounting i get a error: mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'. Did I forget something?

I have added information of the server to the main topic.